# There is event click for combobox in autocomplete Jquery?

Tags: jquery, combobox, jquery-autocomplete

I read native [tutorial](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox) but had not found nothing about events.
I need that after click by field input will be opened dropdown menu.

Answer (score 0):

You should check the [API documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#events) of the jquery-ui autocomplete, specifically the events sections.
There are several possible events you can use there, however I'm not sure from your question what exactly you are trying to achieve.

If you want to trigger some function after a specific element was clicked, you should use the [select](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-select) event:

```
$( ".selector" ).autocomplete({
    select: function( event, ui ) {
        // Do something once an element in the autocomplete menu was selected
    }
});
```

If you want the autocomplete to get "show" once another element was clicked, you should use something like this:

```
$('#element').click(function() {
    $("#autocomplete").autocomplete('search', 'a');
});
```

In this example, once you click on the element with the id="element", the autocomplete will do a search for the letter 'a' and open the results. You can read more about the [search method here](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#method-search).

I hope this helps